# Problem instantiating struct template

Tags: c++, templates

How can instantiate this template struct?

```
template<typename T,
  template<typename, template <typename> class D= std::allocator
           >class Z=std::vector
         >

struct amen
{
    Z<T,D<T> > cc; // i know D template class parameter is not visible , how do i do it?
};

int main(){
amen<int> moreAmen;
}
```

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this wrong. It should be

```
template<typename U, typename D = std::allocator<U>
         > class Z = std::vector
```

The allocator of `std::vector` is not a template. Then the declaration of `cc` becomes

```
Z<T> cc;
```

As you gave a default argument for the allocator, you don't need to pass any argument for it. If you wanted to, you would need to pass `std::allocator<T>` or some other allocator again

```
Z<T, std::allocator<T> > cc;
// or T<T, my::funny:allocator> cc;
```

The default argument of a parameter of a template template argument is not "inherited" to the corresponding template template parameter of your class/struct template. You need to specify it again, like above (by stating `std::allocator<U>` as default template argument).

Comment: but std::allocator is function template or class template then?, since we need to specify the template-id , thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The template signature of `std::vector` is `<typename, typename>`, and not `<typename, template <typename> class>`.

Comment: @MrAnubis, It's a class template. Just like you can say `template<typename C, typename D = std::vector<C> >` you can say the above.